# error with mocha karma test runner

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

My directory structure is:

```
karma.conf.js
GruntFile.js
src
  -MyModule.js
lib
  -bar.js
test
  -MyModule.test.js
  -test-main.js
```

This is my karma.conf.js file

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sat Aug 08 2015 08:09:40 GMT+0530 (IST)

module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs','chai'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  {pattern: 'lib/**/*.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'test/**/*.test.js', included: false},

  'test/test-main.js',
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: false,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: [],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
})
}
```

this is lib/bar.js

```
module.exports = function (a, b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

this is src/MyModule.js

```
var bar = require("../lib/bar.js");

module.exports={
  add:function add (a, b) {
    return bar(a, b);
  }
}
```

and this is test/test-main.js

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
    allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
  }
});

require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base',
  paths: {
    '../src/MyModule.js': '../src/MyModule.js',
    '../lib/bar.js': '../lib/bar.js'
  },
  deps: allTestFiles,
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

and this is the test/MyModule.test.js

```
var MyModule = require('../src/MyModule.js');
describe('A test suite', function () {
var expect = window.expect;

beforeEach(function () {

});

afterEach(function () {

});

it('should add the two numbers', function () {
    var  abc = MyModule.add(1, 3);
    expect(abc).to.be.equal(4);
});
});
```

When I am running the test I get the error

```
Error: Module name "../src/MyModule.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the function `add()` somehow needs be accessible from within the local scope of the test, eg.:

```
describe('A test suite', function() {

   /* ... */

   var add = function(a, b) {return a+b;};

   /* ... */

});
```

alternatively, the `require()` function can be used to load further scripts.

Comment: I have modified the src/index.js to src/MyModule.js and added the following code 
     module.expors={
      add: function (a, b) {return a+b} 
    }
but its still not helping

Comment: put the test through the JS debugger once - that function probably won't be within the *local scope* of `it()`. there's lots of examples: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html - you have to consider that the test has it's own scope - just like the code to test has it's own scope. that asynchronous done(); callback is also useful.

Comment: `module.exports.add = function(a, b) {return a+b;} `

Comment: `require('src/MyModule.js');`